# terminal via null-modem cable

Tags: linux, terminal

How to get the Linux terminal via null-modem cable on-the-fly (without editing /etc/inittab file)?

Answer (score 0):

Run a getty (such as agetty or mgetty) against the appropriate device.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`minicom`](http://alioth.debian.org/projects/minicom/).

Comment: This is an ancient post, but please consider expanding the answer.  Just pointing to a product isn't considered an answer by current standards because it doesn't indicate anything about why it's a good solution or how to accomplish the solution.  Good guidance on recommending software [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).  Thanks.